# Missing directory separator for image source

Tags: magento2, product-images

I just finished installing magento 2 using composer and run it under apache virtual host mymagento.com. When I open the homepage the product images are not loaded and when I check on my console, There is a separator error in the image path. A separator is missing between the product and cache directory. Can anyone suggest a fix for this problem ? 
[image]

Comment: at which point you have defined catalog/product?